# Janusgraph OLAP traversal - Connection with cassandra using trusstore config not working

Tags: gremlin, graph-databases, olap, spark-cassandra-connector, janusgraph

We have a working setup of [Janusgraph 0.5.2 version](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/releases/tag/v0.5.2) where we are able to insert and query ([OLTP](https://www.oracle.com/database/what-is-oltp/)) the data as per need.
We are exploring [JanusGraph OLAP traversal](https://docs.janusgraph.org/v0.4/advanced-topics/hadoop/) for some [reporting and analytical requirements](https://docs.janusgraph.org/v0.4/advanced-topics/monitoring/).
However when I try to follow the instructions provided on the JanusGraph documentation, we are not able connect to [Cassandra](https://docs.janusgraph.org/v0.4/storage-backend/cassandra/) when we try to traverse the graph.
[Cassandra](https://cassandra.apache.org/_/index.html) is setup on [SSL connection](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/cics-tg-zos/9.3.0?topic=ssl-how-connection-is-established) with a [Truststore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/318441/truststore-and-keystore-definitions) on client side. This configuration connection with Cassandra from [Gremlin Console](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/current/tutorials/the-gremlin-console/) works fine with [OLTP traversals](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/javadocs/3.2.9/full/org/apache/tinkerpop/gremlin/process/traversal/Traversal.html).

Below is config for [OLTP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39910552/olap-and-oltp-queries-in-gremlin) which works [`janusgraph-cql-oltp.properties`](https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/blob/master/janusgraph-dist/src/assembly/cfilter/conf/janusgraph-cql.properties):

```js
gremlin.graph=org.janusgraph.core.JanusGraphFactory
storage.backend=cql
storage.hostname=cassandra.cassandra.svc.cluster.local
storage.username=cassandra
storage.password=cassandra123
storage.cql.keyspace=janusgraph
cache.db-cache = true
cache.db-cache-clean-wait = 20
cache.db-cache-time = 180000
cache.db-cache-size = 0.5
storage.lock.wait-time = 60000
storage.cql.ssl.enabled=true
storage.cql.ssl.truststore.location=/etc/config/tls/gremlin/client/truststore
storage.cql.ssl.truststore.password=secretpasswd
```

When I load this line in gremlin console to connect and traverse a simple query I am able to.

Below is the config for OLAP which is showing error for connection to Cassandra:

```py
gremlin.graph=org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.hadoop.structure.HadoopGraph
gremlin.hadoop.graphReader=org.janusgraph.hadoop.formats.cql.CqlInputFormat
gremlin.hadoop.graphWriter=org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.NullOutputFormat

gremlin.hadoop.jarsInDistributedCache=true
gremlin.hadoop.inputLocation=none
gremlin.hadoop.outputLocation=output
gremlin.spark.persistContext=true
# # JanusGraph Cassandra InputFormat configuration
# # These properties defines the connection properties which were used while write data to JanusGraph.
janusgraphmr.ioformat.conf.storage.backend=cql
# This specifies the hostname & port for Cassandra data store.
janusgraphmr.ioformat.conf.storage.hostname=cassandra.cassandra.svc.cluster.local
janusgraphmr.ioformat.conf.storage.port=9042
janusgraphmr.ioformat.conf.storage.username=cassandra
janusgraphmr.ioformat.conf.storage.password=cassandra123
janusgraphmr.ioformat.conf.storage.cql.keyspace=janusgraph
janusgraphmr.ioformat.conf.storage.lock.wait-time = 60000
janusgraphmr.ioformat.conf.storage.cql.ssl.enabled=true
janusgraphmr.ioformat.conf.storage.cql.ssl.truststore.location=/etc/config/tls/gremlin/client/truststore
janusgraphmr.ioformat.conf.storage.cql.ssl.truststore.password=cassandra123

janusgraphmr.ioformat.conf.storage.ssl.enabled=true
janusgraphmr.ioformat.conf.storage.ssl.truststore.location=/etc/config/tls/gremlin/client/truststore
janusgraphmr.ioformat.conf.storage.ssl.truststore.password=cassandra123

janusgraphmr.ioformat.conf.storage.cql.read-consistency-level=ONE

storage.lock.wait-time = 60000
storage.cql.ssl.enabled=true
storage.cql.ssl.client-authentication-enabled=true
storage.cql.ssl.truststore.location=/etc/config/tls/gremlin/client/truststore
storage.cql.ssl.truststore.password=cassandra123

janusgraphmr.ioformat.conf.cache.db-cache = true
janusgraphmr.ioformat.conf.cache.db-cache-clean-wait = 20
janusgraphmr.ioformat.conf.cache.db-cache-time = 180000
janusgraphmr.ioformat.conf.cache.db-cache-size = 0.5

cassandra.input.partitioner.class=org.apache.cassandra.dht.Murmur3Partitioner
cassandra.input.widerows=true

# # SparkGraphComputer Configuration #
spark.master=local[*]
spark.executor.memory=1g
spark.serializer=org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
spark.kryo.registrator=org.janusgraph.hadoop.serialize.JanusGraphKryoRegistrator
```

When i load the graph object in the gremlin console, i can see the properties are loaded correctly.
But when i traverse the graph as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.janusgraph.org/advanced-topics/hadoop/#olap-traversals-with-spark-local), I get cassandra connection error related to ssl config.

```js
gremlin> graph=HadoopGraph.open('/janusgraph-full-0.5.2/conf/olap.properties')
==>hadoopgraph[cqlinputformat->nulloutputformat]
gremlin> g=graph.traversal().withComputer(SparkGraphComputer)
==>graphtraversalsource[hadoopgraph[cqlinputformat->nulloutputformat], sparkgraphcomputer]
gremlin> graph.configuration()
//// i can see all the properties from the file loaded here
gremlin> g.V().limit(1)
07:34:44 WARN  org.apache.tinkerpop.gremlin.spark.process.computer.SparkGraphComputer  - class org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.output.NullOutputFormat does not implement PersistResultGraphAware and thus, persistence options are unknown -- assuming all options are possible
com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.NoHostAvailableException: All host(s) tried for query failed (tried: cassandra.cassandra.svc.cluster.local/10.0.165.158:9042 (com.datastax.driver.core.exceptions.TransportException: [cassandra.cassandra.svc.cluster.local/10.0.165.158:9042] Connection has been closed))
Type ':help' or ':h' for help.
```

I can verify from my cassandra logs that a connection was attempted but request was rejected for ssl reasons. Below are the logs from cassandra instance:

```json
INFO  [epollEventLoopGroup-2-4] 2023-05-02 07:34:58,809 Message.java:826 - Unexpected exception during request; channel = [id: 0xeb0e017f, L:/10.12.0.224:9042 ! R:/10.12.0.135:60316]
io.netty.handler.ssl.NotSslRecordException: not an SSL/TLS record: 0400000001000000500003000b43514c5f56455253494f4e0005332e302e30000e4452495645525f56455253494f4e0005332e392e30000b4452495645525f4e414d4500144461746153746178204a61766120447269766572
        at io.netty.handler.ssl.SslHandler.decode(SslHandler.java:1057) ~[netty-all-4.0.44.Final.jar:4.0.44.Final]
        at io.netty.handler.codec.ByteToMessageDecoder.callDecode(ByteToMessageDecoder.java:411) [netty-all-4.0.44.Final.jar:4.0.44.Final]
```

Can someone help on the way [SSL configuration](https://docs.janusgraph.org/master/configs/configuration-reference/) needs to be passed to [Gremlin](https://tinkerpop.apache.org/gremlin.html) for [OLAP traversal](https://www.datastax.com/blog/mechanics-gremlin-olap) on [JanusGraph](https://docs.janusgraph.org/schema/)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you try the following config options instead?

```
cassandra.input.native.ssl.trust.store.path
cassandra.input.native.ssl.trust.store.password
```

You can find how they are used from CqlConfigHelper.java. Unfortunately, the official doc does not mention this.

Comment: I tried the above options but now a different error is coming up, indicating that it accepted the details provided and failed further ahead in the process to connect. @BoxuanLi
The error details point to version mismatch in the jars used at runtime and compile time.
The error is - 
`Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: DEFAULT_SSL_CIPHER_SUITES
        at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlConfigHelper.getSSLOptions(CqlConfigHelper.java:533)
        at org.apache.cassandra.hadoop.cql3.CqlConfigHelper.getCluster(CqlConfigHelper.java:315)
       ..... ....`

Comment: I just noticed you are using 0.5.2. Could you try version 0.6 or 1.0? 0.5 is not officially supported anymore and a lot of things have changed in 0.6. In theory, you can continue using your OLTP on 0.5 while running OLAP on 0.6/1.0.

Comment: If using 0.6 does not work, you may want to follow-up on this issue: https://github.com/JanusGraph/janusgraph/issues/1727

Comment: thank you for the inputs. i did recreate the problem in local with 0.5.2 and verified that latest version of Janusgraph does have this problem addressed.

Comment: I have documented the details in this post. 
https://dev.to/archcode01/janusgraph-olap-traversal-not-working-with-cassandra-backend-with-client-ssl-enabled-3c4f